# Trying to find out my Google Business Admin User Name

Tags: google-workspace

I am trying to find out what the user name is for my Google Business Admin. I have tried many times to find the "need Help' that Google refers to under the Sign In button but cannot find it.

I need to login and rectify some email issues.

Comment: At this time Google doesn't have a "Google Business" service. Is your question about [Google Apps for Work](http://www.google.com/apps/)?

Answer (score -1):

Google Apps admin accounts do not have usernames - you login with your Google email address and password. You can determine if the gmail account you are using is an admin by clicking on the grid menu in the upper right; if the account has admin privileges, the menu will have an **Admin** icon under **More**.

[image]

Comment: All Google accounts have at least one username, the main email address.

Comment: The username is just part of the email, e.g. if admin@myorg.com is the email, admin is the username. Logging in with just the username does not work in Google Apps; the full email address is required.